# Is there anything Quantikz can do that Tikz cannot do?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I am learning how to draw quantum circuits. I was checking the options available and I could see that Tikz and Quantikz are suitable for making circuits diagrams but I want to know if there are some tasks that Quantikz can do but Tikz cannot. Thanks.

---

[Cross-posted on Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553152/103128)

Comment: +1. While there is indeed this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/ A question specifically about quantum circuits will probably be more likely to be seen by the right people here than there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: this is a good question per se but off-topic. People here might be interested in it but that doesn't change the fact. It should be asked on tex.SE

Comment: @user1271772 Technically that's the right place for it, but I'm more likely to see a question here (as the author of quantikz).

Comment: @DaftWullie so basically my whole comment is right, why would you use the word "but" ?

Comment: @user1271772 Sorry, I had muddled the "here" and "there" in reading it

Comment: It's with some reluctance that I have to close this question. While it's technically off-topic here, it's nonetheless a good question

Answer (score 5):

As Michele Amoretti correctly says, Quantikz is built on top of Tikz. It cannot do anything that Tikz cannot. It is simply intended to provide a wrapper that makes it more convenient for doing the specific tasks associated with drawing quantum circuits.

More specifically, it's done in a way that **I** find most convenient (as the package author!). Mostly it came about because I'm writing a text book which contains hundreds of circuit diagrams, and I needed that convenience, but knowing that Tikz does a beautiful job of graphics in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this tutorial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03842.pdf), Quantikz is a Tikz package that is specific for drawing quantum circuits. So they are not alternative solutions.